# LINQ Query to get values from database at specified time intervals

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

I want to fetch values from database with specific intervals in C# and need a LINQ query for that.
This is what my database looks like

```
Id      SensorId  Value       CreatedOn   

1         8        33.5       15-11-2012  5:48 PM     
2         5        49.2       15-11-2012  5:48 PM 
3         8        33.2       15-11-2012  5:49 PM
4         5        48.5       15-11-2012  5:49 PM
5         8        31.8       15-11-2012  5:50 PM  
6         5        42.5       15-11-2012  5:50 PM  
7         8        36.5       15-11-2012  5:51 PM  
8         5        46.5       15-11-2012  5:51 PM  
9         8        39.2       15-11-2012  5:52 PM  
10        5        44.4       15-11-2012  5:52 PM  
11        8        36.5       15-11-2012  5:53 PM  
12        5        46.5       15-11-2012  5:53 PM  
13        8        39.2       15-11-2012  5:54 PM  
14        5        44.4       15-11-2012  5:54 PM  
..        .        ....       ...................
```

The interval is in minutes. 
So, if the interval is 10 minutes, then we need the values at 5:48,  5:58, 6:08 and so on...

This is what I have tried

```
while (startDateTime <= endDateTime)
            {
               var fetchIndex =
                    fullValues.Where(
                        item =>
                        item.CreatedOn >= startDateTime &&
                        item.CreatedOn < startDateTime.AddMinutes(1)).Select(
                            item => item.FetchIndex).FirstOrDefault();
                if (fetchIndex != 0)
                {
                    var temp = fullValues.Where(item => item.FetchIndex == fetchIndex).ToList();
                    result = result.Union(temp);
                }

                startDateTime = startDateTime.AddMinutes(interval);
            }
```

Since the while loop iterates through the table, it takes a lot of time to get these values.

Is there any way of getting the data in a single query?

Answer (score 2):

```
from x in table
where   x.CreatedOn >= startDateTime &&
        x.CreatedOn <= endDateTime &&
        (x.CreatedOn.Minute % 10) == 0
select x
```

this will give you 1:00,1:10,1:20

The 10 represents your interval and 0 is your offset.

Comment: It gives the following error message
Cannot apply operator % between DateTimeOffset and DateTimeOffset

Comment: @MayurDhingra: make sure that you are applying the '%' operation between two integers.

Comment: But how can i do that. The requirement is for DateTimeOffset DataType and not integers.

Comment: x.CreatedOn.Minute, the .Minute Type is int and the interval type is int. please post your code if that doesn't resolve your problem.

Comment: This won't return 5:48, 5:58, 6:08 for the asker's sample data.

Comment: +1 Very nifty solution, if the starting time is 05:58 `(x.CreatedOn.Minute % 10) == 0` is just changed to `(x.CreatedOn.Minute % 10) == 8` or whatever is the remainder and it works.

Comment: @IvanG That relies on the interval being 10.

Answer (score 2):

Following approach creates a list `requiredTimes` which holds all of the relevant datetimes between `startDateTime` and `endDateTime` (datetimes in 10 minute intervals between start and end datetimes).
After such list is created the `fullValues` is inner joined on it. The result is an IEnumerable with datetimes from `fullValues` that satisfy the interval condition. It should work fast since creating such list is quick and the `Join` method is an inner join which should also work fast, try it:

```
        DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.Parse("15-11-2012 5:48 PM");
        DateTime endDateTime = DateTime.Parse("16-11-2012 5:58 PM");

        List<DateTime> requiredTimes = new List<DateTime>();

        DateTime dt = startDateTime;
        requiredTimes.Add(dt);
        while (dt <= endDateTime)
        {
            dt = dt.AddMinutes(10);
            requiredTimes.Add(dt);
        }

        var result = fullValues.Join(
            requiredTimes,
            fv => fv.CreatedOn,
            rt => rt,
            (fv, rt) => fv);
```

Comment: Good idea!  You can make assigning the requiredTimes a single statement:

`var requiredTimes = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue).Select(x => startDateTime.AddMinutes(x * interval)).TakeWhile(t => t <= endDateTime).ToList();`